# Two different textbutton are not responding on LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

    public void show()
    {
        buttonsAtlas = new TextureAtlas("Color.pack"); //button atlas image
        buttonSkin = new Skin();
        buttonSkin.addRegions(buttonsAtlas);
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("CustomFont.fnt"), false); //the font

        stage = new Stage(); // window is stage
        stage.clear();

        TextButton.TextButtonStyle style = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle(); // button properties
        style.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("Red");
        style.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("Blue");
        style.font = font;

        gameButton = new TextButton("Game Screen", style); //button text and style
        gameButton.setPosition(-250, 500); //button location
        gameButton.setHeight(600); //button height
        gameButton.setWidth(1200); //button width

        shopButton = new TextButton("Shop Menuuuu", style); //button text and style
        shopButton.setPosition(100, 500); //button location
        shopButton.setHeight(600); //button height
        shopButton.setWidth(1200); //button width

        stage.addActor(shopButton);
        stage.addActor(gameButton);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        gameButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                gameButton.setBounds(-250, 500, 100, 100);
                Gdx.app.log("my app,", "pressed");
                game.setScreen(new inGame(game));
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log("my app", "released");
            }
        });

        shopButton.addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                shopButton.setBounds(100, 500, 100, 100);
                Gdx.app.log("my app,", "pressed");
                game.setScreen(new Shop(game));
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log("my app", "released");
            }
        });
    }

    public void render(float x)
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        game.batch.begin();
        stage.draw();
        game.batch.end();
    }

    public void dispose()
    {
        batch.dispose();
        buttonSkin.dispose();
        buttonsAtlas.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }
```

I am trying to make two `TextButton`s to work at the same time. However there is always one button showing on the screen, which is the last button that was being added to the stage. In this case it is the `gameButton` because it is the last button that was added to the stage.

How do I make both button work?

Comment: Your code works fine, I suppose that the problem is with the size of your buttons. Why are width and height of buttons so big?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in setting negative Coordinate, may be you need to understand Coordinate systems for game:
o,o is at bottom left corner of screen
so when you give negative value, that part is not being displayed.

so two images are overlapping in your case and stage gives z index to actors and object which is added last will have highest z index, that means last added object will be draws on top of others.

What you need to do:

```
gameButton.setPosition(0, 0); //x,y --absolute to bottom left corner
gameButton.setSize(200,200); //width, height

shopButton.setPosition(200, 0); //x,y --absolute to bottom left corner
shopButton.setSize(200,200); //width, height
```

also doing setbound inside actionlistner is not good idea

Comment: They are actually overlapping over each other. Now I understand better about coordinate system. Thank you so much!